# C++ 14 Eigen load too slow

Tags: c++, performance, installation, codeblocks, eigen

I use C++ 14 with Eigen and CodeBlocsks IDE.
How should I integrate/install Eigen correct?

First of all, please see this [imagine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvcnp.jpg)

Is this the right way to append Eigen to my project? In other topics I observed #include<Eigen/Dense> but this won't work for me.

The main problem is that when I run my project (Build and run) it load too slow, too much time to open the console, this problem come from Eigen? From Eigen I use only linear algebra facilities (Matrix, Vector, methods for determinants, QR decomposition) Can I make something to load only this file instead of all Eigen components? or how should I solve the problem about slow loading?

Comment: You don't load all Eigen components. Only files you `#include` and their depandancies. For more information, attach your CMake / compile-link instructions.

Comment: Are you compiling your code with or without compiler optimizations enabled?

Comment: I don't know about compiler optimizations, please give me more details @JesperJuhl

Comment: Where can I see CMake/ compile-link instructions? @BennyK

Comment: @dacian See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/o-options-optimize-code?view=vs-2019

Comment: @dacian How do you "Build" your project? This is also relevant to the second comment regarding optimizations.

Answer (score 0):

Do not put Eigen code directly in your project. Instead, install it to another location on your system and connect your project to it - for example, if you're using CMake, use `find_package(Eigen)`.

The easiest way to install libraries is to use a library package manager such as [vcpkg](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg).